# create-react-app (react redux) Multiple actions in connect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

I am creating a React app with Create-React-App using Redux.

Following a tutorial, all the actions are put into 1 file:

src\action\index.js

```
export const fetchUser = (useCache = false) => async dispatch => { .. }
export const getUser = (useCache = false) => async dispatch => { .. }
export const fetchAlerts = (useCache = true) => async dispatch => { .. }
```

and then I connect them to my components using Connect:

```
import * as actions from "../../actions";

....

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Home);
```

However I would like to organize my actions into files, having a Accounts Action, and a Alerts action for this example. And I may want to call functions from each action in the 1 component.

My problem I'm having is I cant figure out how to add multiple actions into the 1 connect statment:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Home);
```

The actions accepts an object or a function... Arrays dont work..

Comment: If i am correct you want to map all these actions in your Home component right ?

Comment: yes that's right. I want a logically split the code in files, but i also want access to all Account and Alert actions

Comment: I have added the answer how you generally maps multiple dispatch actions as props to your component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, since you know mapDispatchToProp param of connect() can be object as well, you can always use

```
Object.assign({}, userAction, alertAction)
```

Or with object spread operator

```
{...userAction, ...alertAction}
```

Answer (score 0):

To map all the actions to your Home component with redux you can do something like:

```
import * as actions from "../../actions";

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchUser: (useCache = false) => dispatch(fetchUser),
    getUser: (useCache = false) => dispatch(getUser),
    fetchAlerts: (useCache = true) => dispatch(fetchAlerts)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

See if this helps.